# Unable to extract images from a pdf with pdfimages

Tags: pdf, images

I'm traying to extract images from a PDF with `pdfimages`. The last time I used it I had no problems, but now I can't do the job.

When I run

```
pdfimages archive.pdf .
```

and I try `ls` in the folder where the pdf is located, I get nothing. With `ls -a` I found hidden files like `.-000.ppm`

Why is `pdfimages` producing such an output? How can I get again the images?

Comment: I did the same thing. The command ran for a while and seemed to work but there was no output. The command help output is quite ambiguous and I'm sure that using `.` is a common issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The manpage to `pdfimages` says

> `pdfimages [options] PDF-file image-root`

So, your command

```
pdfimages archive.pdf .
```

instructs `pdfimages` to create the output files with filenames starting with a `.` - and this is exactly what happened, only that such filenames happen to have a special meaning in Unix/Linux.

You can either re-run the command with a more conventient value for the `image-root` parameter, or rename the (involuntarily) hidden files, which should still contain the correct output (i.e. the extracted images).

Comment: Thanks AdminBee, problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the pdfimages manpage. The second parameter "image-root" is a prefix. You told pdfimages to prefix the extracted images with a dot. They are  images totally valid filenames, albeit hidden. You can proceed to use them as they are.

Comment: Ok thanks Hermann, I fixed the problem. I used the dot because I thought the last argument was the location of the folder where the I wanted to extract the images.